# How to test for multiple conditions (longitude and latitude)?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

so I'm trying to analyze tweet sentiment values from specific timezones. I am trying to check a specific timezone that has certain longitude and latitude coordinates. How do I test for multiple conditions in an if statement? Or in a for loop? Do I put brackets or something?

```
 for line in infile:
        line=line.rstrip()
        words=line.split()
        firststriplat=words[0].rstrip(",")
        lat=firststriplat.lstrip("[")
        lat=float(lat)
        long=words[1].rstrip("]")
        long=float(long)
        easternlat=lat>=24.660845 and lat=<49.189787
        easternlong=long>=-87.518395 and long=<-67.444574
        if easternlat and easternlong:
```

Comment: Have you tried exactly this code? In what way does it not do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: Logical expressions can be grouped with `(`, `)` like arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can do something like this to check whether an variable is within a specific range:

```
if (24.660845 <= lat <= 49.189787) and (-87.518395 <= long <= -67.444574):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a bracket, what type of conditions are you testing for ?, I.e how many

For example if you have multiple > and ==,

You could do something like.

(Con A == con B) and (conC == conD)